# Comparing two proportions within contingency table for small sample size

Tags: r, p-value, proportion, fishers-exact-test, z-test

I need some help for a statistical analysis.

I have the following contingency table :
[image]

I would like to compare p3 and p2, that is the comparing the proportion of event in G2 and the proportion of not-event in G1. How it is possible ? I have a small sample size : p1 = 3, p2 = 4, p3 = 8 and p4 = 2.

Thanks for your help